# Android: Receiving touch at the bottom views

Tags: android, touch-event, android-windowmanager

I have a `fullscreen layout` added to the `windowManager`. In the layout, I have a few controls e.g. a `keyboardView`. The `keyboardView` can listen to touches but anything behind the layout can't receive any touch even though some area of the layout is transparent.

Is there a way the controls behind the layout get the touches as well as the `keyboardView`. At the moment, I can receive touch on either part but not both.

This is my code I have when added to the window manager.

```
View out =  mKeyboardSwitcher.onCreateInputView(mIsHardwareAcceleratedDrawingEnabled);
        WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        layout.addView(out, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        manager.addView(layout, lp);
```

The reason I wanted to have layout to be full screen coz I want the keyboard to be draggable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, your view top of each other and in order to listen their touches you have to use CoordinateLayout